# Find the general solution of the second ordinary linear homogeneous differential equation when a singular solution is a second order polynomial.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

I am having problem solving an  ODE.

This is the equation:

$(x-1)y'' - (x+1)y' + 2y = 0$

So I started with y1 = ax^2 + bx + c, and since this is a solution I substituted its first and second order derivative on the equation and I got stuck here:
bx + 2c - 2a = 0

Can anyone help?

(I tried another example that had an exponential solution and it worked cuz I could factor stuff and all but here it's just ?! Maybe I did sth wrong?)

Comment: Hello, it is useful if you show what you have tried to do so far yourself, that would make it better for your learning process.

Comment: Hint.

First, determine which values for $a,b,c$ make $y_1 = a x^2+b x + c$ a solution and after that through variation of parameters, order reduction, you can obtain the other solution $y_2$

Comment: I agree.  In your  question, show us what the polynomial solution is.  Then show us what happens (at least until it gets too complicated) when you use that to find another solution.

Comment: This can be solved using Kovacic algorithm. A solution can be seen [Here](https://12000.org/tmp/02182022/foo_2.pdf)

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much!!